# How do I fix my ethernet card losing network connection every few minutes with kernels 3.8.x?

Tags: 13.04, networking, kernel, acer, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. My laptop is Acer Aspire one 722-c58rr, and my ethernet card works for a few seconds at a time with kernels 3.8.x, however, kernels 3.5.x and below worked fine.

On kernels 3.8.x, it works fine after boot for about a minute, then it looses network connection. When pinging to some address, it says: `network address is unreachable`, but it can ping it's own address. The address is statically configured.

Everything was working fine before. I went to vacation, where I used WiFi and 3G connections, so I didn't notice that the problem occurred. Came back home, plugged in into the ethernet. It worked for a minute then stopped. Rebooting commutator fixed the problem. Tried to connect to a different commutator, same problem. Unplugging and plugging the cable fixes the problem for another minute. Disconnecting `eth` in Network manager and reconnecting it again, does the same thing. WiFi has no such problem.
Tried to use a different cable that works fine on another computer, the same problem.
Tried to boot with the lower kernel version, the same problem was happening until I got to the version 3.5 of the kernel series.

Everything works fine on the kernel 3.5.x, but I don't want to miss out on the new kernel's features.

Executing commands, when booted with 3.8 kernel series, give the following results:

```
  lspci| grep -i eth:
    06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)

  dmesg| grep eth1:
    [ 89.548291] atl1c 0000:06:00.0: atl1c: eth1 NIC Link is Up
```

How do I fix it, while staying in the new kernel version?

Comment: what's the result of `lspci  | grep -i eth` and `dmesg | grep eth0` (where eth0 is your network interface)

Comment: @Cubiq - lspci| grep -i eth:<br/> 06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)<br/>; <hr/>dmesg| grep eth1:<br/> [ 89.548291] atl1c 0000:06:00.0: atl1c: eth1 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>

Comment: @igoryonya Please **edit** your question to include it in it. As you can see comments aren't fit for this and on Q&A sites we improve questions rather than posting like a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you slipped into a kernel bug for your particular ethernet card (bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173279) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/680239)). I suggest you to post your feedback to those threads.

It seems that removing and adding back the `atl1c` module fixes the issue temporarily:

```
sudo rmmod atl1c
sudo modprobe atl1c
```

Another more durable solution is to recompile the `compact-wireless` module you [can find on kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2) like so:

```
sudo rmmod atl1c
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential wget
wget http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2
tar-xjf compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless*
scripts/driver-select atl1c
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe atl1c
```

If it doesn't work try to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, the best solution is to update your kernel to the latest, as the fix was included in 3.11 and later kernels.

I'm not posting how to update the kernel manually because it's very easy to find tutorials by just googling "updating linux kernel in ubuntu" or somesuch.